# Does androidTest support flavors and build type variants?

Tags: android, testing, build-variant

Does *androidTest* support flavors and build type variants?

```
flavorDimensions "foo"
productFlavors {
  full {
    dimension "foo"
  }         
  trial {
    dimension "foo"
  }
}
```

If there is only src/androidTest/java, which variant to test?

Comment: You can run the tests against any variant you want.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#create_instrumented_test_for_a_build_variant for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create tests for specific flavors in `src/androidTestFull` and `src/androidTestTrial`. Any tests that are common to all flavors go in `src/androidTest`.

> The instrumented tests in src/androidTest/ source set are shared by all build variants. When building a test APK for the "MyFlavor" variant of your app, Gradle combines both the src/androidTest/ and src/androidTestMyFlavor/ source sets.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#create_instrumented_test_for_a_build_variant)

Comment: what if i wanna do the same with build type .. Like i wanna run both espresso and unit tests on only stagging build type of a specific falvour..

Comment: @AdeelTurk If you want to run tests against a specific build type, you can specify it in the folder name: `src/androidTestStaging` or `src/testStaging`. You can combine build types and flavors to run specific tests: `src/androidTestTrialStaging` or `src/testFullDebug`.

Comment: please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046482/i-want-to-run-unit-test-and-espresso-test-cases-a-specific-build-type as it might help anyone else

Comment: It doesn't works for me. Whatever folder I created, androidTestMyFlavor for example, it depends on BuildVariant choosen. It not affected by folder name.

Comment: @Alexmelyon Yes, you still have to select the Build Variant to run. If you select "My Flavor" then Android Studio will run the tests in `androidTestMyFlavor`. If you select a different build variant then it won't run those tests.